# create a new module remotely

Tags: cvs

I've checked out a cvs module:

```
cvs -d :pserver:user@server.org:10010/data/cvs/xxx co -kk MODULENAME
```

If it's allowed by admins, how can I create another module in same repo?

Comment: `cvs import` is what you are after. You can look it up in any cvs documentation.

Comment: @BurhanAli Nobody should be obliged to read docs in 21st century. That's why SO exists

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Usually modules are defined in CVSROOT/modules, check it out, edit it and check it back in:

```
cvs co CVSROOT
vi CVSROOT/modules
cvs commit
```

However real CVS modules are basically a kind of “virtual collection” which for example allows a module named “TEST”
to refer to multiple directories to be checked out.
Developers who don’t know about modules often refer to “modules” in terms of directories. Then they would simply
fork all the code and commit it to a new directory called NEWMODULE. So the code is simply checked in to a directory
and not using CVS modules functionality:

```
export CVSROOT=:pserver...
cvs import -I ! -m "My initial project message" NEWMODULE mycompany start
```